# Mobile Hidden Menu works on jsfiddle but not online. Any solution would be helpful.

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

So, I was using the root JS Fiddle of the below URL (part before 761) and I got a nice design that works exactly how I wanted it. Here's the link:

[Click here to see whole JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzDjA/761/) and here is the Javascript code:

```
$('#trigger').click( function() {
    if ($('#popout').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('#popout').removeClass('hidden');
        showPopout();
    }
    else {
        $('#popout').addClass('hidden');
        hidePopout();
    }
});

function showPopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
        top: 49
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('|||');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}

function hidePopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
        top: -150
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('|||');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}
```

But when I implement it here: http://m.bwpcommunications.com/agency.php it doesn't work.

Anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be setting the click handler before the DOM has loaded.

You can see that, by changing your fiddle to load jQuery "in head" (like your live site), your code stops working.
http://jsfiddle.net/tzDjA/764/

You may need to add the following around your click handler.
This will configure your handler after the DOM has loaded.

```
$(function() {

  $('#trigger').click( function() {
    [...]
  }  

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzDjA/762/

Alternatively, try [delegating](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) the handler so that it will be applied to elements that are added to the DOM later.

```
$(document).on('click','#trigger',function() {
  [...]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzDjA/763/

Comment: That works! Thank you! If I had the reputation I'd give you some props.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load jQuery on this page: http://m.bwpcommunications.com/agency.php 
jQuery UI is not the equivalent of jQuery.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Thanks :)  I looking around a bit as well, the functions all seemed right. But, where is jQuery? ;)

Comment: Thanks for all of responses! I've now added jQuery but that didn't fix it. I'm going to try @showdev solution. I'll update ya'll with results... brb.

Comment: @Shadna I've see that you've added jQuery now.  You still need to have this for your script to work.